# Partition of numbers

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

Find all $\alpha_i, 1\le i \le n$ and $\beta_j, 1 \le j \le n$, $\alpha_i, \beta_j \in \mathbb{N} $ satisfying the following:

> (1) $\alpha_i  \ge \alpha_{i+1}$ for $1 \le i \le n-1$ and $\beta_j  \ge \beta_{j+1}$ for $1 \le j \le n-1$.
>
> (2) $\Sigma \alpha_i = \Sigma \beta_j$.
>
> (3) the sets $\lbrace \alpha_i +i-1 \rbrace_1^n$ and $\lbrace \beta_j +j-1 \rbrace_1^n$ are same.

Comment: Why the number theory tag? Perhaps real analysis?

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ are non negative natural numbers. ThanX @Elliot..

Comment: I haven't visited Project Euler for quite a while now, but this problem certainly reminds of their style.